# Create 32-bit COM object from 64-bit cscript script

Tags: activex, visual-sourcesafe-2005, wsh

I have a JScript script which is called by `cscript`. That script creates Visual Source Safe ActiveX object using `new ActiveXObject("SourceSafe")` code in it's internals.

Everything was ok on 32-bit windows. But on 64-bit windows I need to call 64-bit version of `cscript` and still use 32-bit ActiveX object (SourceSafe). 64-bit version of `cscript` doesn't see that ActiveX class (because 32-bit class is in 32-bit branch of windows registry).

Is there any way to create that object from 64-bit cscript? (except writing 64-bit automation adapter for SourceSafe ActiveX class)

Comment: That's not possible.  Using c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe is the simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have created COM+ server which aggregates SourceSafe COM component (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). It took less than a minute. After that I can create `SourceSafe` object in out-proc server using the following simple code:

```
WScript.CreateObject("SourceSafe")
```

How it works (my understanding): COM+ 64-bit out-proc server marshals automation calls to COM 32-bit out-proc server which delegates calls to 32-bit in-proc server.